# What is the accuracy of scf=qc when convergence criteria is lowered?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I am trying to run single point calculations with Gaussian 09 for a Mulliken population analysis on large graphene/graphite (940-1411 atoms) sheets/clusters.

I was having difficulty with memory issues (single CPU license) running `DFTBA` for single point calculations. I have stepped my convergence (beginning with `conver=1`, and increasing by reading in my previous checkpoint files).  I found my results oscillating and failing.

I decided to try `scf=(qc,conver=5,maxcycle=500)`.  This worked, which concerned me.

It not only worked, but it worked much faster than my failed `sp` calculations.  I know Gaussian's old default convergence for single point calculations was N=4.  As my calculation was done in less than two hours compared to the days it was taking for `DIIS`, I have become concerned at the accuracy of the QC using `conver=5`.  I cannot find anything indicating my approach is bad, but also I cannot find anything syaing my approach should yield reasonable results.

Can anyone please tell me if this approach is reasonably accurate?

Answer (score 5):

Something that I have discovered is that when Gaussian (or other good ab initio software) fails to converge, there is something sketchy about what one is trying to calculate. Sometimes DFT calculations just aren't appropriate, especially in cases that require multiconfigurational SCF for even a zero-th order description.

In this case, given the sheet-like character, I suspect the problem is that the molecular orbitals are so close together, and so similar, that there are serious linear dependency problems that lead to all sorts of havoc in the linear algebra routines and convergence accelerators.

If you are trying to simulate an infinite sheet, then I suggest that you try plane wave codes like those found in solid state chemistry (Gaussian's PBC code, NWChem, abinit, etc.)  These sorts of calculations have gotten easier in recent years, but sometimes they require serious horsepower.

There really does seem to be a problem with SCF convergence, and this could be because you are approaching some kind of band structure limit. I have always used QC as an absolute last resort when I *must* do something wacky.

(One other thing, you have "capped" your peripheral benzenoid rings with hydrogens?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

First I must ask, why do use QC as a last resort?  I tried as such expecting an error due to memory.  Everything I have read suggests it is more memory intensive, but at the same time more reliable.  It was because of that I became very concerned about the speed of my single point runs (roughly 1/4 of the time my SP-DIIS calculations).
If you avoid QC for other reasons, please let me know.

Comment: Next, yes I have tried different configurations of the substrate.  I started with a simple single layer graphene; capped my edges of that graphene with hydrogen; am currently running a double layer capped with hydrogen (so far DIIS only); and have graphane and a pure double graphene to try.

My geometry is set up according to accepted theory (although it is completely pristine).

Comment: I think that QC calculates the orbital Hessian w.r.t. the coefficients.  That's awfully expensive, when there are other methods which could get the job done faster. My point is that there seems to be something pathological with your molecular system, which is why DIIS doesn't work, and why you have to tweak convergence criteria even on QC -- the most robust convergerer known to humankind.

Comment: another question: is Gaussian complaining about linear dependencies?

Comment: My challenge is to accomplish my calculations using the given software on a single cpu and with the memory limitations.  I had read publications where they were quite successful doing something similar, using DFTB and SWNT (albeit much smaller surfaces).  Our sheets need to be at least 32x32 Angstroms.  When my convergene was oscillating I too suspected an issue with molecular orbital overlap, which is why I began "capping" my ends and set up a fully saturated graphane.  I will certainly give the PBC code a try.  Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: No, it is not mentioning anything about linear dependence. In doing the full print, I can see the steps and they are most definitely stuck in an oscillation.

Comment: Eric, your first comment on what (or rather how) it does its calculations is what had me the most concerned.  For a system of my size and a robust calculation, it shouldn't have converged so quickly.

Comment: Eric...You have given me another idea of how to double check the calculations.  Let me give that a go.  I know folks don't normally complain when calculations are fast, but it was a huge red flag for me when it took less than four hours to complete on a 940 atom system (using QC that is).  Unless being stuck in the oscillation caused the problem (extreme long run time prior).
The only reason I have had to tweek my convergence criteria for QC has been for memory limitations.  I have found I can overcome quite a lot by stepping my convergence to where I want.

Comment: I will take another look at my geometries.

Comment: You need to be careful.  If you are running into linear dependency problems Gaussian may not always tell you.  It likes to drop the suspect basis functions when it can instead.  Be sure to check your output file at the beginning and end to make sure that the number of basis functions used did not change.  This is very important to take note of.

Comment: @Linda You may have a more symmetric structure, even if it is a larger molecule.  This might be much faster to compute and converge.

Comment: @EricBrown, I am not sure I follow your last statement.  I went back through my basic structure today (no hydrogen termination) and cleaned it up (set all of my bond lengths to exactly 1.418).  Is that what you were suggesting, or are you saying I may have too much symmetry?

Comment: @Linda I think you definitely want H terminations (should be like benzene around the periphery) Otherwise there will be trouble.  Symmetry:  it is possible that a large structure with high symmetry (e.g. D2H) will compute faster than a smaller structure with lower symmetry (e.g. Cs).   You may want to make sure you are using the highest Abelian symmetry group as possible.

Comment: @EricBrown, Well I can't thank you enough!  We followed your advice and for the first time I understand what a symmetrical calculation actually looks like.  Going back through my old files Gauss had switched to nosymm on my old graphene files.  I have been able to leave the system the size we wanted (1476 atoms) and we finally got convergence for our hydrogen terminated sheet (10^-4, running for 5 now), and I was able to do so in one step with no memory issues.  For our final sheet we used geometry for xy instead of defining bond lengths and brought our SD for the same down.  Thanks again!

Comment: @EricBrown, I think I have also answered my original question.  I tried the qc on DFTBA with a much smaller system.  The rigors of the qc calculations don't appear to start until N=6 in Gauss.  When I finally have my susbtrate optimized I am going to go back and compare my results to the qc calculation at conver=5, see how well it compares.